# SSRS 2008 R2 master detail not refreshing whole report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I was wondering if it is posible in SSRS 2008 R2 (or SSRS 2012) to setup action filters that refreshes partially the report (without reloading the whole report).

Something like a master-detail. On top a grid with the master rows. Below a pie chart showing graphically the results of all rows.

When user clicks on a master row the pie chart is refreshed with data that only applies to the selected row. The refreshing I expect would be something like an ajax update (ie not reloading the whole report).

Can this be done with SSRS 2008 R2 or SSRS 2012? Any example?

Comment: There isn't a straightforward way to do this, but there are some workarounds. Probably the easiest method would be to have the report call a stored procedure that updates a table with the data only if the data needs to be refreshed and then returns the contents of the table.

Comment: SSRS doesn't really support that kind of interactivity, you could look at platforms like Tableau or Power View for that kind visualisation.